# Downloading using php header('Content-Type....) breaks the request

Tags: php, file, download, request, header

I've been trying several things and I've looked for an answer here but I haven't found anything. Therefore I'm asking the question.

I'm not sure if it is an error or if it is the way this is suposed to work.

**What I'm doing (and works perfectly)**

1. I've written a code that parses a xlsx file and decides what rows have to be inserted in the DB, and what rows have to be rejected because they contain errors (this part works perfectly).
2. Step 1 generates an array that contains all the rows that have problems (plus a column with info about the error). (This works perfectly).
3. With the array generated in step 2 I create a form element that contains a serie of inputs  with the serialized info of the rejected rows + The information of the rejected rows for the user to see (this also works perfectly).
4. In this form, there's a button that triggers the form to be sent via POST. When this is done, all the rejected rows travel thorough POST and a $_POST variable named "confirm_upload" is set. (this works perfectly)
5. When step 4 is done, the page is refreshed and within the controller (the part that manages user actions) if the $_POST['confirm_upload'] is setted, the form created in step 3 is processed, generating a xlxs and downloading it for the user to inspect why those rows were rejected. The code user for the one shown below (And works perfectly).

```php
         $lines_to_download = array_merge( array($header) ,$rep_lines,$conf_lines,$error_lines);
    
         $spreadsheet = new PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
         $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
         $sheet->fromArray($lines_to_download, NULL , 'A1');
       
         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
         header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8'); 
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. urlencode("uninserted.xlsx").'"');
         header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate;');
         header('Expires: 0');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
         header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($spreadsheet));
       
         ob_clean();
         flush();
         $writer = new PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
         $writer->save('php://output');
```

**What's the problem?**

The problem is that, the same $_POST['confirm_upload'] that triggers the download, is supossed to change the template in the view, so the user no longer see the list of rejected lines, but the template doesn't change. I've checked in the favicon, and the form refreshes the page, but, for some reason, the view is not affected by $_POST changes.
**I've commented the lines related to the download, and when they are commented, the VIEW do refresh properly**. SO **it's obvious** that for some reason, **the download process prevents the  $_POST variables affect the view** (although theey are obviously sent, because if it was not the case, the download would not take place).

Specifically, the view is properly affected by the $_POST changes if I comment this lines (but, obviously, then the file do not download):

```php
         header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');  
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. urlencode("lineas_no_insertadas.xlsx").'"');
```

I've also tried adding Header("location: index.php ") and header(Refresh: 0), but they don't do anything. I've tried everything, including all the combinations of commenting one line and leaving the others, deleting some headers, keeping the headers to the minimim. At the end, anything but commenting those two lines, blocks the request (so the view remains unafected), because the download breaks the request.

Is it the way it is supossed to work or there's something else that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can't see the rest of your code. If file is uploaded, echo content showing the errors along with a new button with a new name for downloading the content - if that new download button is clicked echo something else to hide the errors.

Comment: @SJacks I don't understand what you are trying to say with your comment. There are no errors shown ANYWHERE in the code (I'm inspecting the 'echoed' HTML element by element and there are no php errors triggered). It's just that the request stops once the download begins.

Comment: We have a crossed line. I was referring to the errors (rejected rows) you mentioned which you are displaying, not PHP errors.

Comment: This is part of a process that works perfectly and is before the download. Once the two cited lines are commented, the view is changed (but obviously no download takes place). Once the two cited lines are uncommented, the download takes place properly, but the view do not refresh.  

PD: I've isolated the problem and it still happens, so I guess this is the way it's supossed to work. I am coding a work around that will work perfectly.